# Recursive loop in Xslt 1.0

Tags: recursion, xslt-1.0, bi-publisher, oracle-apps

I am working on a recursive loop. Below is the sample code.

The loop gets executed only once. It is not executing until it reaches the maximum count (20 times).

Can you please help if this is an issue?

Thanks,
Raj

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xdoxslt='http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.apps.xdo.template.rtf.XSLTFunctions'>
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:variable name="nl">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#xD;'"/>
      <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:template match = "ARCHIVE_CHEQUE_WRITER">
      <xsl:for-each select="CHEQUE">
         <xsl:variable name="ded" select="./AC_DEDUCTIONS"/>
         <xsl:variable name="dedcount" select="count($ded)"/>
         <xsl:variable name="earn" select="./AC_EARNINGS"/>
         <xsl:variable name="earncount" select="count($earn)"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$dedcount"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$earncount"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>        
         <xsl:text>Starting New Record*******</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="./AC_DEDUCTIONS">
                  <xsl:text>This is sample template</xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="recursive-loop">          
            <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="20"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="recursive-loop">
      <xsl:param name="pStart" select="1"/>
      <xsl:param name="pCount"/>
      <xsl:text> value of parameters</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pStart"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pCount"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>    
      <xsl:if test="$pCount > pStart">
         <xsl:call-template name="recursive-loop">
            <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$pStart+1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>   
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: did the answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use $ for variable pStart in the template

```
<xsl:if test="$pCount > $pStart">
    <xsl:call-template name="recursive-loop">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$pStart+1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```